# Invalid View Tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to add view tags to ad group, and I am always receiving the same response:

```html
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter", 
    "type": "FacebookApiException", 
    "code": 100, 
    "error_subcode": 1487248, 
    "is_transient": false, 
    "error_user_title": "Invalid View Tags", 
    "error_user_msg": "The view tags are invalid."
  }
}
```

I make a POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com/<AD_GROUP_ID>` with `view_tags=["https://cdn.thenextad.com/1.php"]`

The pixel seems to satisfy all requirements from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adgroup/#view_tag_requirements).

Do you have any ideas that might help?

Comment: that view tag looks invalid, surely it should be https:// not https:\\

Comment: +1, that URL definitely isn't valid - i'm also unsure if thenextad is an approved view tag provider - check with your account manager

Comment: @PaulBain you are right. Unfortunately, I just removed the wrong slashes from the encoded version, so the link is valid (https://cdn.thenextad.com/1.php)